# Becoming; airtight - usage in the presented contexts

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am pleased to join the community.

I would like to confirm whether it is correct to say:

1) "He employed becoming means to alleviate harmful effects of (...)"

2) "He managed to pinpoint the problem with airtight accuracy."

3) "He undertook surgical steps to address the issue (...)" (surgical serving as a synonym for accurate)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ***none*** of these seem correct, either idiomatically or directly, as written.

**Option 1** is incomprehensible.

**Option 2** makes little sense (pinpoint accuracy is in fact a common phrase, laser-like precision, surgical precision are also) as "airtight accuracy" is not a common phrase or concept - I would simplify with: "He managed to pinpoint the problem", as pinpoint *already* implies a high degree of precision.

**Option 3** I could see re-writing as: "He undertook corrective steps with surgical precision" to clearly indicate that the steps chose to correct the issue were ***only*** those required directly to correct the issue with no waste, no unnecessary actions or collateral impacts.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think the second and third to be correct, either. Why is the first one incomprehensible to you, though? Here's more obvious re-statement: "he used appropriate ways to reduce harmful effects of."

Comment: "appropriate means to alleviate" would work, or "appropriate means to remediate harmful effects" could also work depending upon context... "appropriate ways" is a conflict in register "appropriate" is a higher-register conceptual word, whereas "ways" is a lower-register more generic conceptual word - I'd try to identify a tonal register and stick with it. I'm *guessing* (as you've not provided contextualising information) that this needs to hit a professional tone and register. "Surgically precise steps" would work, BTW.